# fetch data from database in minimal time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, performance

I am using mysql and node.js. I have a button 'load previous chat' to load chat of two users.
When i am clicking on that button it is giving result @ 12 lines/second (tested manually).How can i make it fast?
Here is my code

On server side-

```
socket.on('chatHistory', function(data){
    var count=0;
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM chatRecord WHERE uniqueRoomId = '"+data.roomId+"' ", function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;


        for (var j in result) 
        {
            if (rows3.hasOwnProperty(j)) count++;
        }
        var k=0;
        if(result[0])
        {
            socket.emit('chatHistoryMaintain', {result:result,sum:count,nickname:data.nickname});
        }
    });
    });
```

Client side Code -

```
socket.on('chatHistoryMaintain', function(data){
    for(i=0;i<data.sum;i++)
    {
        if(data.result[i].sender==data.nickname) 
        {
          $('#chat-messages ul').append('<li class="marker"><div class="fl sender">'+nickname+' : </div><div class="fl text1">'+data.result[i].msg+'</div></li>');
        }
        else 
        {
          $('#chat-messages ul').append('<li class="marker"><div class="fl receiver">'+nickname+' : </div><div class="fl text">'+data.result[i].msg+'</div></li>');
        }
     }
});
```

How can i optimize it more as my application is giving results @ 12 lines/second whereas skype is as fast as 1560 lines/second ? What i am doing wrong?

Here is details of my database engine

```
>     +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
>     | Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
>     +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
>     | PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
>     | MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
>     | MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
>     | BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO      
> |
>     | MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
>     | CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
>     | ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
>     | FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
>     | InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
>     +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Can have a couple of reasons. Is there an index on column uniqueRoomId? How many rows does chatRecord have? Which engine is your database using? Can you post an explain of your query? Do you have details on your server's hardware?

Comment: yes uniqueRoomId has index. chatRecord has 30,000 rows.I have edited my question for database engine details.  what do you want to know about server hardware?

Comment: I was pointing at the engine your table uses, sorry for the mislead. 30000 rows should not stress your db too much. Did you try to execute your query directly in the DB via PMA or Workbench? If it is faster there, your problem might not be the query and/or database, but postprocessing of the data.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it faster you first must find out why is it slow in the first place

1. Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to find out if your query is doing row scan or using indexes and which ones.
2. if you feel harassed by EXPLAIN output, try doing `SELECT COUNT(*)...` with same `WHERE` clause instead. If it is slow too, the index is probably the problem.
3. Check if doing the query from cli client is also that slow

If the problem is in query doing row scan, adjust your indexes. If mysql has no problem finding the data but rather returning it, don't wait for all 30k records to be pumped through socket to return them all in one batch. Consider using asynchronous fetching of rows instead (it's node.js after all!), as described in [official doc](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows). Putting a lot of records in node.js process memory at once is not a good idea, you can try monitoring memory usage of the process.